# javascript bzip2 stream as Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, string, bzip2

From a previous answer on Stackoverflow I found the bzip2 lib for javascript: https://github.com/antimatter15/bzip2.js

It does pretty much what I need, except that I need the output as a Uint8Array instead of a string.

I use this function from the bzip2 lib:

```
bzip2.simple = function(bits){
   var size = bzip2.header(bits);
   var all = '', chunk = '';
   do{
       all += chunk;
       chunk = bzip2.decompress(bits, size);
     }while(chunk != -1);
    return all;
}
```

I found a way of transforming the string output into a Uint8Array :

```
function str2ab(str) 
{
     var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
     var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
     for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
     }
     return buf;
};
```

But for speed reasons I was hoping there was a good way to re-write the original bzip2 function so it directly outputs as a Uint8Array.

One of the main problems I’m having is that I don’t know how to dynamically increase the array.